# Integrating MSAL ADB2C with VS 2017 Angular template

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm working on integrating Azure B2C into my Angular App.  I've been able to take examples from the web (VS Code Angular projects) and get them working with MSAL, but for some reason, I cannot do the same in Visual Studio 2017 Angular Template.

I'm not sure what the magic trick is... Here's what I've tried:

1. Declaring MSAL as an `:any` object, then included the `CDN <script>` tag in my index...  It gives me a "window is undefined" error message when I do this.
2. I've tried `npm install msal` and then `import * as msal from 'msal';`  This also did not work ("window is not defined").

I'm kind of new to Angular, but I've been able to import and utilize other packages just fine.  It seems to be MSAL.

Does anyone have an idea how to get this working with MSAL v0.1.5 and Visual Studio 2017 Angular ASP.NET Core template?

Comment: Which Angular template?  The [new one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?tabs=visual-studio) or the [old one](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/)?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I may have at least one solution to this problem: Disabling pre-rendering in ASP.NET Core.  My <app> tag had an asp-prerender-module attribute.  When I removed this my code started working.  The ASP.NET Core pre-rendering must have some incompatibility issues with packages.

Hope this helps someone!

James

Comment: pre-rendering works in [this Angular sample](https://github.com/Gimly/NetCoreAngularAzureB2CMsal/blob/master/Views/Home/Index.cshtml), fyi.